# @injectMocks does not work when using spring aop

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-aop

I'm writing junit and I using @mock and @injectMock.But,I find @injectMocks doesn't work when bean in spring aop.code like this:

QuestionService.java:

```
@Component
public class QuestionService implements IQuestionService{
  @Resource
  private IUserService userService;
  @Override
  public User findUserById(long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    User user = userService.findUserById(id);
    return user;
  }
}
```

Test.java:

```
@Mock
IUserService mockuserService;
@InjectMocks
@Resource
QuestionService questionService;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testfind() {
    when(mockuserService.findUserById(1)).thenReturn(
            new User(1, "name"));
    User user = questionService.findUserById(1);
    Assert.assertEquals(new User(1, "name"), user);
}
```

It works!

But,when I add userService in spring aop,It does not work!

For example, transaction aop.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting behavior - once I used the AOP around **any** method in the class, the mocks stopped working; instead the 'real' component was initiated although there was no code for that matter. 
I found that if you were to use @MockBean - everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you annotate `QuestionService` with `@Resource` in test class? Are you running with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` by loading bean configs? If not remove `@Resource` annotation and try, doesn't matter whether using AOP or not, it should work.

And add below snippet of code in `@Before` method of your test class as first line.

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

**@InjectMocks** : Mark a field on which injection should be performed.
**MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)**: initializes fields annotated with Mockito annotations.

Comment: Yes, I run with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner..If questionService has userService which I want to mock and tagService which I want to load by spring, How can I do？

Comment: tagService where it comes from? please update your question.